# Google Extended Trends API for Health: Quota for FluTrends queries per day

Tags: google-api, google-trends

I'm currently planning to write my Master Thesis on the topic "Geographical inequalities in access to abortion services". My Professor got access to the extended Google Health Trends API end of April 2022, but she didn't create an API key back then. She invited me to join the project about one month ago. I was then able to create an API key. Unfortunately, I cannot make use of the extended Trends API because there is no FluTrends query quota available for me or my Professor (it seems that the query quota needed for the extended health API is still called "FluTrends query quota").

I tried to ask the API support team, but they are not responding. I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a chance to get the query quota, or if the Google Trends API support team became inactive? Unfortunatly, using the trends website (e.g. pytrends) isn´t really an option for me.
Many thanks!

Comment: Google Trends does not have an API.  I question what api you are referring to because if you are using some kind of third party scraper its probably against googles TOS.

Comment: Many thanks for the response! I´m referring to the extended Google Health Trends API / GHT (for further information see: https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/19/22/15396). For this API it´s necessary to ask Google for permission to be able to use the data. The thing is that I have been granted access and I can create an API key. However, you need the query quota mentioned above to make queries. I cant set the quota myself, and can´t request it via the console. Therefore i am dependent on the support team.

Comment: I think you need to talk to google if this really is an official api.  I can find no information on it.   I dont think your going to get any help here.

Comment: It would be great if there was the possibilty to talk to google, but unfortunatly I´m not getting a response. I´m asking here because - as you mentioned - it´s very hard to find information online. I know that chances are low, to get information here, but I have reached a point where I am using every opportunity to obtain information

Comment: Contact your Professor  they have been granted access somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, unfortunately google isnt responding to my professors emails either.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortuantely not. I have the feeling, that there is no more support for the API.